# Failing to send requests with cURL and PHP

Tags: php, http, post, curl

I am developing a flight-monitoring software for flights in Brazil and I am having some trouble to successfully receive the flights data from the website. It is in ASP.NET and I believe there must be multiple requests to be fullfilled before it actually shows the data.

I already am getting the ASP.NET-specific variables (like EVENTVALIDATION and VIEWSTATE) and sending the multiple requests (one sending the airport and the other sending the post) but it still is a no-go.

The page where you select the airport and airline is this http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx, but the data is shown here http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index_2.aspx.

The code is not optimized, as I am still in debug. Thank you in advance for any help at all.

```
<?php

// Sets the server variables for this script
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
ini_set("default_charset", "utf-8");

// Sets the cookie
$cookie = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookies/cookiejar.txt";
$fp = fopen($cookie, "w");
fclose($fp);

// Slices the string to the the viewstate value
function GetViewState($result)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $doc->loadHTML($result);  
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');  

    for($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++)
    { 
        if ($nodes->item($i)->getAttribute('name') == "__VIEWSTATE")
        $viewstate = $nodes->item($i)->getAttribute('value'); 
    }

    return $viewstate;
}

// Slices the string to the the eventvalidation value
function GetEventValidation($result)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $doc->loadHTML($result);  
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');  

    for($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++)
    { 
        if ($nodes->item($i)->getAttribute('name') == "__EVENTVALIDATION")
        $eventvalidation = $nodes->item($i)->getAttribute('value');  
    }

    return $eventvalidation;
}

// Sends a request only to retrieve EVENTVALIDATION and VIEWSTATE values
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
$viewstate = GetViewState($result);
$eventvalidation = GetEventValidation($result);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Sends the received VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION values, as well as the airport (SBCF)
$ch = curl_init();
$postfields = "ScriptManager1=update|aero_companias_aeroportos";
$postfields .= "&__EVENTTARGET=aero_companias_aeroportos";
$postfields .= "&__EVENTARGUMENT=";
$postfields .= "&__LASTFOCUS=";
$postfields .= "&__VIEWSTATE=".$viewstate;
$postfields .= "&__EVENTVALIDATION=".$eventvalidation;
$postfields .= "&pode_pesquisar_aeroporto=S";
$postfields .= "&aero_companias_aeroportos=SBCF";
$postfields .= "&txt_num_voo=";
$postfields .= "&txt_water_box_ClientState=";
//echo $postfields;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
$viewstate = GetViewState($result);
$eventvalidation = GetEventValidation($result);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Sends the same as the previous request, plus the form
$postfields = "ScriptManager1=update|btnPesquisar";
$postfields .= "&__EVENTTARGET=";
$postfields .= "&__EVENTARGUMENT=";
$postfields .= "&__LASTFOCUS=";
$postfields .= "&__VIEWSTATE=".$viewstate;
$postfields .= "&__EVENTVALIDATION=".$eventvalidation;
$postfields .= "&pode_pesquisar_aeroporto=S";
$postfields .= "&aero_companias_aeroportos=SBCF";
$postfields .= "&aero_companias_companias=Selecione%20uma%20Companhia%20A%C3%A9rea";
$postfields .= "&txt_num_voo=";
$postfields .= "&txt_water_box_ClientState=";
$postfields .= "&btnPesquisar=Consultar%20Voos";
//echo $postfields;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
$viewstate = GetViewState($result);
$eventvalidation = GetEventValidation($result);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Shows the page with the results
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index_2.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

?>
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Are you using `curl_error()` to see whether the calls succeed?

Comment: I am only getting the airport selection page back, no results. I tried curl_error(), they are all clean.